# Ubuntu Server 16.04 - Firstboot script help

Tags: 16.04

I am working on setting up an automated install to put on machines that will not have access to the internet. I have a package of required .deb files that I have downloaded, since there will be no internet. I have got a good preseed file, that sets up the partitions, installs the OS, and copies the post install packages to the machine. I have a late_command that copies and runs a script that sets a post_install script to run at first boot. This script extracts the packages.tar file, sets the extracted directory as a source, then installs the required packages.

This is where the help comes in. Everything works, up to installing the packages. the logs show what looks like them getting installed, but none of them are actually installed. When I run the script manually after the install, it runs just fine, and installs the packages. Anyone have any experience with this?

Post_install script:
http://pastebin.com/dvM1prt8

firstboot log:
http://pastebin.com/xSdDBSzA